# How do I get the charging time from given database?

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I have a problem. I want to find time diff between row values when their value is changed. I have the following similar data in my table, For ex:

```
------------------------------------
    DateandTime     |    DCStatus
------------------------------------
2012-01-01 01:00:00 |    Using
2012-01-02 02:00:00 |    Using
2012-01-03 03:00:00 |    Using
2012-01-04 04:00:00 |    Charging
2012-01-05 05:00:00 |    Charging
2012-01-06 06:00:00 |    Using
2012-01-06 07:00:00 |    Using
2012-01-06 08:00:00 |    Using
2012-01-05 09:00:00 |    Charging
2012-01-05 10:00:00 |    Charging
2012-01-05 11:00:00 |    Charging
------------------------------------
```

From this given database How can I calculate the average charging time and discharge time? I am very new to SQL programming. Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this using a standard query as far as I know. You have two options:

- use stored procedures and MySQL [programming constructs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html) to achieve the desired effect
- query the data and use the programming language you are building the rest of your application in to process it

If you are not specifically forced to do this calculation in the database, I would suggest the latter option - programming languages are generally more suited to these kinds of calculations and your application will be less dependent upon MySQL as a database.

Answer (score 0):

```
select avg(Time(DateandTime)) from yourTable where DCStatus = 'Charging' or DCStatus = 'DisCharging' group by DCStatus;
```

I'm not sure this works in MySQL, I don't have time to test it, but it should work.

Comment: You are a life saver Man, Thanks. I just had to make a small change 

`select avg(Second(DateandTime)) from yourTable where DCStatus = 'Charging' or DCStatus = 'DisCharging' group by DCStatus`

Comment: Hello Lajos!!! When I calculate average, I don't think the where is clause is being of any use. With or Without where clause it returns the same result which is wrong.

Comment: If that's true you probably don't have entries where DCStatus differs from both 'Charging' and 'DisCharging'